# How to request a fullscreen on new window?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an element on my document into a fullscreen display but to do so on a new browser window. If you Alt+Tab on your screen, it will show both the new fullscreen element as well as the original document body on two separate windows.

The reason why I wanted to do this is because I am currently running a dual-monitor setup such that the element will be displayed on the second monitor instead of the first when you go fullscreen using the following Javascript snippet which I have done successfully. [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/multi-screen-window-placement/#new-fullscreen-options).

```
const screenDetails = await window.getScreenDetails()
if (screenDetails.screens.length > 1) {
        var elem = document.querySelector("#defect-map-table-main")
  
        try {
          const projectorScreen = screenDetails.screens[1]
          console.log(projectorScreen)
          await elem.requestFullscreen({screen: projectorScreen})
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.name, err.message)
        }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. you want an element to show up in a new tab?

Comment: on a new window instead of a tab then display that window in fullscreen mode